# Moq / Unit Test Unable to Catch Exception unless stepping through code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq

I have a Unit Test, that is expecting an Exception as the return parameter.

If I run the code through the Debugger, and inspect various elements it works.
If I just run all th tests, it doesn't.

The issue has to be something to do with the fact that the method is Async, as if I remove the various Async elements it works as expexted. (I guess its a timing issue)

my unit test is;

```
  [TestMethod]
  [ExpectedException(typeof(System.AggregateException))]
  public void Service_GetDoc_ThrowsExceptionIfNull()
  {
        var nullRepository = new Mock<CCLDomainLogic.Repositories.DocRepository>();
        IDD emptyDoc = null;

        nullRepository
          .Setup<Task<CCLDomainLogic.DomainModels.Doc>>
          (x => x.GetDocAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
          .Returns(() => Task<CCLDomainLogic.DomainModels.Doc>.Factory.StartNew(() => emptyDoc));

        DocService s = new DocService(nullRepository.Object);

        var foo = s.GetDocAsync(1).Result;
    }
```

And the code (abbreviated is)

```
    public async Task<Doc> GetDocAsync(int id)
    {
        Stopwatch timespan = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            ...                
            {
                var t = await Task.Run(() => _repository.GetDocAsync(id));
                ...
            }
            timespan.Stop();

            if (t == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("DocService.GetDocAsync returned Null Document");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error in DocService.GetDocAsync", e);
        }
    }
```

So how do I rework this test to catch the excpetion when running async.
And as a bonus question, can I modify my unit test so I can check for specific exceptions, not the Aggregate Exception?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing all of the code - and from what I see I think that you don't need the Async in the first place, as you start a Task just to await it - why don't you just use `_repository.GetDocAsync(id)` and only move into a thread if you have to?

Comment: Well teh async / task thing is somethign I copied from elsewhere, I'll go back and re-read to make sure I am using it correct.
My Moq ensures that the reposirtory returns null, and throws the exception, I just can't understand wht it doesnt propogate up to the unit test.

Comment: From what I can see it should wait (the `.Result` part) - but maybe there is something more in `...` - aside from this you don't really need something like `await Task.Run(...` if you don't want to use cancellation or timeout

Comment: Thanks. Changing the Test Method to be async,and the last line to await s.GetDocAsync(1); did it.

Now lets hope that when I go through and remove some of those extra tasks I was starting, that nothing else breaks :-)

Comment: that is what the tests are for :D

Comment: btw: I did see this only now: the `GetDocAsync` already returns a task - in this case you should **not** use this `Task.Run` overload anyway: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382(v=vs.110).aspx ("The Run(Func(Of Task)) method is used by language compilers to support the async and await keywords. It is not intended to be called directly from user code.")

Comment: Just do `var t = await _repository.GetDocAsync(id);` instead

Comment: Thanks. Shame I can't give you a tick :(

Comment: It's a bit hard as I did nt really give an answer - I just provided you with some hints and you did the work - so maybe write an answer yourself and mark it as answered as soon as you can - this is really no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your test runs async code that executes after the assert has already run (or not).
Using the debugger only give the async code more time to workl.
In order to test your code all you have to do is chnage the return type of your MTest to Task and add *await* to thje relevant call:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(System.AggregateException))]
public async Task Service_GetDoc_ThrowsExceptionIfNull()
{
    var nullRepository = new Mock<CCLDomainLogic.Repositories.DocRepository>();
    IDD emptyDoc = null;

    nullRepository
        .Setup<Task<CCLDomainLogic.DomainModels.Doc>>(x => x.GetDocAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(() => Task<CCLDomainLogic.DomainModels.Doc>.Factory.StartNew(() => emptyDoc));

    DocService s = new DocService(nullRepository.Object);

    var foo = await s.GetDocAsync(1).Result;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps without the .Result